# Embedding C in HTML

Tags: web-applications, browser

Is it possible to embed C programs and execute in web browser. I have .so files and i need to use the functions in .so files in a web app. Is this possible?

Comment: What server-side technology do you use? (PHP, ASP.NET, RoR...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely not possible, you'll need to evaluate the code server side and include it in the web response.